# django i18n how to create multilingual apps

Tags: django, internationalization

Is there any analytical step by step guide in order to create i18n multilingual applications with .po files and then use trans command in template language?

Answer (score 2):

You must use `gettext` and check the [PO files](http://docs.transifex.com/formats/gettext/). Django Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/